# Terminal or Command Line

Tags: command-line

Where is the terminal or command line in ubuntu 14.04 LTS? I can't seem to find it. Can you please direct me to find it so I can type in the formula for caffeine so I can stop my screen from dimming? Please advise asap. Thank you, Dianne